How do I reattach a fixture to my all-glass shower?
I had an all-glass shower installed in 2021.  It has a metal towel bar glued to the outside.  We came back from a trip to find that one end of the bar had detached from the glass, and the bar is now hanging by its other end.
What's the appropriate adhesive and surface preparation to re-glue the detached end?

Epoxy should work, if surfaces are cleaned and degreased properly. Maybe too well?
